# Replace with sed after the first occurence of specific word - Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Original file:

```
bla bla test
blabla
start
test
blabla
start
test
```

The result should be:

```
bla bla test
blabla
start
edit
blabla
start
edit
```

So after the first occurence of "start" all "test" should be replaced with "edit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed '/start/,$s/test/edit/g' file

bla bla test
blabla
start
edit
blabla
start
edit
```

**Explanation:**

```
/start/,$      # find text from first occurrance of start till end
s/test/edit/g  # in the found text replace test by edit globally
```